# Automatically apply values from a JSON object to input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object returned from the database.  The values in the JSON object came from an HTML page full of input tags.

```
var userTemplate = { };
$("#tabBasic").find($("input")).each(function() {
    userTemplate[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Now I'd like to re-apply the values from the JSON to the input tags on the page.

Is there a way to do this automatically using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just got the assignment reversed.

```
$("#tabBasic").find("input").each(function() {
    this.value = userTemplate[this.name];
});
```

I assume that each input has a unique `name` attribute.

---

You could also pass a function to the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method. The `return` value is assigned as the new value.

```
$("#tabBasic").find("input").val(function() {
    return userTemplate[this.name];
});
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the `.val()` function argument, cool! In this example, however, wouldn't it be better to cut to the chase and select for `$('#tabBasic input')` instead? Maybe even `$('input', '#tabBasic')`?

Comment: @richardneililagan: It depends. Doing an ID selection followed by a `.find()` will actually perform better in some browsers. And `$('input', '#tabBasic')`, while concise is ultimately turned into `$("#tabBasic").find("input")` [under the hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L170-174), so it ends up being slower because of the conversion (and less readable IMO). In most cases, the performance difference between the 3 will be negligible, and it will come down to personal preference. :)